# Adding a text view to class that extends DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Hi so this could be quite a simple question but its really got me stumped. I have a class that extends DialogFragment and I want to add a TextView to the dialog but the constructor for a TextView is

```
new TextView(context)
```

and basically I don't know what to use as the context.

Thanks for helping a noob out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Activities` inherit from `Context`.  Inside of the `DialogFragment` you can get the `Activity` with `getActivity()`, as long as it is attached to one.